How can I create a camera shake for blender from a finished footage shot on my phone/camera
How can I create a camera shake in blender from a finished footage shot on my phone/camera. Plus, what programs are there that can do same thing besides blender. I knew one such program before, but I forgot its name. It was convenient to do it there.
